# 26' U-Haul with 12'x6' trailer from Eugene, OR to Little Rock, AR

Tags: routes

For a 26' U-Haul with 12'x6' trailer going from Eugene, OR to Little Rock, AR, I see Google takes me on Hwy 84 and 80, but I don't like this route. However, it may be the safest and only route to take in May, 2020.  Is there any other route that is viable with these vehicles? I wanted to go trough Salt Lake City and Albuquerque, but I fear that would be too hilly.

---

I think I have decided to use Hwy 84/80 since its recommended and forgo my preference. Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: What's wrong with this route?

Comment: Remember you're driving a significant truck and trailer. These are all big roads, and any of them will do. If you want to go through SLC and Albuquerque, go that way.

Comment: Note that there isn't a very direct interstate route between SLC and Albuquerque, and one of the more direct routes, I-70, is very mountainous and probably not much fun for an inexperienced truck driver.  So you may have to choose between a major detour or two-lane US highways.

Comment: Please do not post 'thank you' answers, instead accept the answer that was (most) helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The interstate highway system is designed for trucks, bigger trucks than you will be driving.  The maximum grade is limited, as are the minimum curve radius and lane width.   Unless you plan to exceed the maximum weight of the truck or trailer, which of course you should not do, you will not exceed the capabilities of the vehicle.

Comment: I think the bigger question would be the capabilities of the driver.

Comment: @NateEldredge if the driver's capability to handle such a vehicle is under question, then the safest part of the trip is going to be the part on the interstate highway system.

Answer (score 3):

A friend and I did an across-country drive using a similar size Penske truck, with an attached flat-bed trailer that was carrying a small car (Honda Prelude). Our journey was from Ohio to southern California.

He did all the driving (thank Ghu!) and we had heavy rain for the first 2-3 days. We only did about 8 hours a day and paused for bit in Phoenix to visit a friend. Anyway, the Penske truck did terribly on uphill grades. It didn't have as much power as a diesel truck does, so we would be going like 40 mph at most up the hills. After a harrowing trip through Albuquerque at rush hour (fun!), we dropped off the trailer in Flagstaff and I drove the car the rest of the way.

The truck was not packed to the ceiling although it had a full complement of furniture (no appliances) and a bunch of books and comic books which added weight. That may have affected performance.

Anyway, if the truck is going to be packed full, and the trailer is carrying a big car or truck, you may want to find the flattest route you can.

Answer (score 3):

There are only a few big hills that I can remember from Denver to Albuquerque. The Raton pass South of Trinidad, North of Santa Fe the Glorieta pass, and then La Posada Hill between Santa Fe and Albuquerque.  I-25 is a nice easy drive.  Not too much traffic, except between Santa Fe and Albuquerque. I think the only tricky part will be the Raton pass.  Just go slow and take your time.  All the other hills have a 3rd truck lane.

I-40 going east is full of traffic and can be stressful.  Going through the canyon out of Albuquerque is the most stressful.  Lots of curves, and wind.  After that it's pretty easy except for the traffic.  Lots of traffic on I-40.

On a side note don't stay overnight in Albuquerque.  There is a LOT of property crime in the city right now.  If you have time check out the blue hole in Santa Rosa.  Super cold blue water.  Don't know if it will be open with the COVID restrictions.

Have a safe trip.